# Using a USB device locally on 2 computers

Tags: usb, computers

I would like to make what I can best describe as a reverse USB switch, where one USB 2.0 device (a dongle) is physically connected to 2 computers (located side by side). The dongle is powered through USB.

I.e. what I'd like to make is a Y-split, with one female going to two males.

Could this be done simply by wiring together 3 cable ends with the appropriate connectors? Do you think the dongle would be recognized locally and useable on both computers? Should I make sure that power only runs from one of the computers?

Comment: Seems more like an [su] question, but it is already answered so I will save the migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to make a Y cable as you describe and get it to work. USB is a point to point connectivity protocol --- that is a single host end connects to single target end. The connection that you describe would be a multi-host single target type bussed connection and USB is not designed to support that.

As a side note you would never want to interconnect the power between two computers either. GND to GND would be OK but not the 5V to 5V.

There are available products that perform a function close to what you want. These are two way USB switch devices that allow for multiple hosts to share one target device - but one at a time through either a mechanical switch/relay or through an electronic switch component.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There's some minor, intervallic communication between the device and host when it's in use, so in this case I'd need to find something that can autoswitch between the two hosts whenever either needs to communicate with it. Maybe it'd also need to queue up communcations. Just guessing something like that doesn't exist and would be overkill to try and make. It seems I could go with software called USB Network Gate, but it's about twice the price of getting a second dongle, so I think I'll opt for that. Thanks again.

Comment: @eee3 - You may find a device that can share the USB device at a higher level as a shared disk resource over a network but the cost just is not worth it. Modern PCs with today's operating systems can be networked together easily, and cheaper, and then you can simply share the USB disk from one computer to the other. Anyway as you say, lower capacity USB sticks these days are almost dirt cheap.

Answer (score 1):

The USB protocol is not designed for this. As already suggested, you can use a switch, or you might want to try an USB over IP solution to share the USB dongle over the network.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbip/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this by simply wiring three cables together.

You need an actual switch. If you google for "usb ab switch" you'll get all kinds of hits for both mechanical and electronic USB device-sharing switches. (Which makes this a shopping question, and therefore off-topic.)