# Custom USB Y cable

Tags: usb, wiring, bad-wiring

I am creating a custom dual female USB Y cable for a hardware modification project in a USB mouse. I have the wiring set up as shown, is it correct?

RED, WHITE, BLACK, GREEN, THICK BLACK from female 1 are all connected to male 1

RED, WHITE, BLACK, GREEN from female 2 are all connected to the middle of the wire of female 1 to male 1 making a connection and insulating the wire so points don't touch.

to my knowledge

Green - D+
White - D-
Black - Ground
Red - Positive
Thick Black - ?? Extra ground??

Will this work if I have a usb mouse in one end and a flash drive in the other

Comment: I wouldn't call any configuration where you split D+ or D- "correct".

Comment: [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/51824/143764)

Answer (score 5):

No. USB connections are point-to-point with a computer or hub on one side and a peripheral on the other side. It's not going to work if you have two peripherals connected together to a computer on a single port.

If you don't have spare ports on your computer you can use a hub and connect the mouse and the flash drive on different ports of the hub.

Comment: I have a usb hub that does this, why can't mine do it either?

Comment: @AbdelSeaf I don't believe that your hub simply connects the white and green wires. It won't work.

Comment: My understanding is that you're proposing to connect the same D+ and D- wires to both the mouse and the flash drive, please correct me if I'm wrong. The USB interface was not designed for this scenario. The hub is a somewhat complex active device that takes two point-to-point data connections and channels them into a single point-to-point connection with a computer or another hub upstream.

Comment: @joribama Yes, the mouse will running off the same cable just the cables from another usb are conjoined. Can you recommend something like an arduino nano or a dijispark to help me with making a hub? What would be the consecuence if I did it? Would it not work or will there be data issues?

Comment: @AbdelSeaf Something like an Arduino would make a very, very slow USB hub...if it worked at all. If you insist on building one, look for an IC that is designed for use as a USB hub.

Comment: I recommend you use an of-the-shelf unpowered hub, like this one: https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-4-Port-USB-2-0-Ultra-Mini/dp/B003M0NURK (keep in mind you have a power limitation when using unpowered hubs)